# Looking for an essay on what it means for a philosopher to repudiate their earlier work

Tags: reference-request, peirce, semiotics

I read an essay some time ago about what it means for an author to declare that their prior work seems 'false' or 'misleading.' The essayist wanted to make some point, IIRC, about how it is not the text that changes but the originator's perception of it. I want to say the author was Peirce, but I haven't been able to find anything. I know this is terribly vague, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I understand that both Wittgenstein and St Augustine changed their minds on major issues. And, of course, there is always Ralph Waldo Emerson, "A  foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds..."

Comment: *A second reason for my writing this book is that I have had more
than my share of problems with this fitting-together of valid truths
in the past dozen years. I have been trying to come to grips with
the ideas of Freud and his interpreters and heirs, with what might
be the distillation of modem psychology—and now I think I have
finally succeeded ... I feel that
it is my first mature work.* -- Ernest Becker, "The Denial of Death"

Comment: "The Denial of Death" was his 9th(?) and last book (he died at the age of 49). The quote above indicates that his views had evolved substantially. Maybe you can find more specific examples if you read the book -- which I would never suggest if I wouldn't also highly recommend it for its qualities alone... "The Denial of Death" is a masterpiece (tho, with what I know now, I'm less sure about its premise... it might have [never been about the death](https://medium.com/atheism101/what-if-it-was-never-the-death-itself-f1f6fe73fb58?source=friends_link&sk=2f8e937596f27f6e582091e2d4fbfb58) after all.

Comment: Putnam declared himself wrong and Peirce right in his [1976 presidential address Realism and Reason](https://www.princeton.edu/~hhalvors/teaching/phi520_f2012/putnam1977.pdf)"*Peirce himself... always said metaphysical realism collapses into incoherence at just
that point... But internal realism - the empirical theory of "Reference and Understanding"- doesn't collapse (I claim). Metaphysical realism was only a picture anyway. If the picture is, indeed, incoherent, then the moral is surely not that something is wrong with realism per se, but simply that realism equals internal realism*".

Comment: Thank you all for the input. I'm familiar with Becker's work, and just read Putnam's address, but neither of those were the text I'm seeking. It isn't a quote or a person as such, but a paper or essay. I don't recall who the author was, but the topic was the relationship between an author and their work, and what it means for someone to repudiate their earlier writing.